# RPi 3 Can't Play MP3 and Some WAV Files

Tags: pi-3

My Raspberry Pi 3 does not play mp3 files, including `example.mp3` that came preloaded.  When I execute `aplay /home/pi/Sounds/example.mp3`, I get the following:

```
Playing raw data '/home/pi/Sounds/example.mp3' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
```

Most wav files can be played without incident.  However, trying to play some of them results in the following:

```
Playing WAVE '/home/pi/Sounds/flint_phone.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
```

Comment: Looks very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208176/arecord-set-params1233-sample-format-non-available-available-formats-s16-l) on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have the same problem with certain .wav files, which play just fine on my mac with afplay

Answer (score 5):

`aplay` cannot play `.mp3` formatted files. For this, I use `mpg321`. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install mpg321` and it works just like `aplay`:

```
mpg321 /path/to/example.mp3
```

---

As for the `.wav` files that `aplay` won't play, they were most likely either corrupt or were incorrectly converted from another format.

Answer (score 0):

For me, mpg321 also didn't work. However, omxplayer did:

```
sudo apt-get install omxplayer
```

and then `omxplayer /path/to/example/mp3`.

Good discussion on the subject: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=241346